# Get the ContextMenu that a ToolStripDropDownItem belongs to?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get `ContextMenu` that a `ToolStripDropDownItem` belongs to?  This is for the purpose of using the `ContextMenu.SourceControl` as the *logical* `sender` to an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>`ToolStripItem.OwnerItem`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owneritem.aspx][1]</del>

That property can be used to walk up the tree of menu items to the top level item... Isn't what you are after just the `Owner` property of the menu?

```
var control = ((ContextMenuStrip)topLevelMenuItem.Owner).SourceControl;
```

Obviously use `as` etc and do your null checks...

*If I am missing the spot perhaps post a code snippet of the menu built via code to clarify the types (ContextMenu vs ContextMenuStrip etc)*

PK  :-)

Comment: Did you even try it?  Casting `OwnerItem` to `ContextMenu` with an `as` statement doesn't even compile (ie: a `ContextMenu` cannot *be* a `ToolStripItem`).

Comment: That's the parent of the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the `Owner` property as a `ContextMenuStrip`.

```
ToolStripDropDownItem t = sender as ToolStripDropDownItem;
if (t == null)
    return null;
ContextMenuStrip cm = t.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
if (cm == null)
    return null;
return cm.SourceControl;
```